# Making two arrays with given length in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make an input function which makes two arrays with a given length. The input will be

```
4
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

For example,

```
given length = 4
arr1 = [1,2,3,4] 
arr2 = [5,6,7,8]
```

This is what I made.

```
def read_input():
    arr1 = []
    arr2 = []

    length = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())

    for i in range(length):
        a = input()
        arr1.append(int(a))

    for i in range(length):
        b = input()
        arr2.append(int(b))

    return arr1, arr2, length
```

First my input is stop after making arr1. I cannot type arr2.
and give me

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 2 3 4'
```

this error.
So what is the problem?

Comment: What is the error you're getting? What is stored in your `sys.stdin`?

Comment: Please elaborate "doesn't work". It works for me.

Comment: I update my question.

Answer (score 0):

`input()` returns the entire line from the input stream, so for your code to work you need to provide each number in a separate line, such as:

```
2
1
2
3
4
```

If you want to provide lists line by line instead, you'll need to split them manually:

```
arr1 = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
arr2 = [int(i) for i in input().split()]
```

In that case you don't really need the length, assuming that the data consistency is guaranteed, which is normally the case in such exercises.

Answer (score 0):

I have a very naive solution. I am considering the list you are giving as input, will be same line. What I mean is that for taking input in `arr1` all the elements for `arr1` will be in same line and same goes for `arr2`

So, here is my solution,

```py
def read_input():
    arr1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
    arr2 = list(map(int, input().split()))

    return arr1, arr2, len(arr1)
```

Note that I didn't take the length as input because it is actually not necessary in python. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
l = 4
arr1 = [i for i in range(1,l+1)]
arr2 = [i for i in range(l+1,l+l+1)]
```

Output:

> arr1 = [1,2,3,4]
>
> arr2 = [5,6,7,8]

Check more here :

[range() function](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_range.asp)